# Prevent Title Edit In post.php

Tags: posts

I am looking for a way to disable the editing of a post's title when on post.php.

I want the title of a post to remain "fixed", but editing of the content to be possible.

```
 function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
     if( !current_user_can('delete_published_posts') ) {  
         remove_meta_box('titlediv', 'post', 'normal');
     }  
 }  
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );`
```

This will completely remove the title box, which somewhat achieves the goal, but I would ideally like to still be able to actually display the Title - just that it can't be edited

Comment: You have posted multiple questions, all of which have received upvoted answers, you should consider marking them as correct if they solved your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple jQuery code to disable the title field.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
poststatus = /* get this from your php code */
if( poststatus != "auto-draft" ) {
jQuery( "#title" ).attr( 'disabled', true );
});
```